# How can I get the Relative/Absolute GAP from LP solution in Python with CPLEX Solver?

Tags: python, linear-programming, cplex, pulp

I'm solving a problem with PuLP in python and i'm trying to print the gap with `solution.MIP.get_mip_relative_gap()` but it doesn't work.
Is there a way to get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [orloge](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/plugins/orloge.html)

Let me share a small example out of the [zoo example](https://medium.com/ibm-data-ai/optimization-simply-do-more-with-less-zoo-buses-and-kids-part2-python-java-c-cc04558e49b5).

```
import pulp
import cplex
import orloge




bus_problem = pulp.LpProblem("bus", pulp.LpMinimize)

nbBus40 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus40', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
nbBus30 = pulp.LpVariable('nbBus30', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

# Objective function
bus_problem += 500 * nbBus40 + 400 * nbBus30, "cost"

# Constraints
bus_problem += 40 * nbBus40 + 30 * nbBus30 >= 300


solver = pulp.CPLEX_CMD(options=['set logfile c://temp//log.log','set mip limits solutions 2'])




bus_problem.solve(solver)
print(pulp.LpStatus[bus_problem.status])

for variable in bus_problem.variables():
    print ("{} = {}".format(variable.name, variable.varValue))


logs_dict = orloge.get_info_solver('c://temp//log.log',"CPLEX") 
best_bound, best_solution = logs_dict["best_bound"], logs_dict["best_solution"]

print("best_bound = ",best_bound)
print("best_solution = ",best_solution)

print("gap = ",abs(best_bound-best_solution)/(1e-10+abs(best_solution)))
```

which gives

```
Optimal
nbBus30 = 1.0
nbBus40 = 7.0
best_bound =  3750.0
best_solution =  3900.0
gap =  0.03846153846153748
```